# Throwing InvalidCapacity and InvalidState exceptions during allocateCapacity / deallocateCapacity

Tags: java, device, redhawksdr

I saw in the documentation for Redhawk's Frontend interfaces [here](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainap9.html#x35-453000I.3) that calls to allocateCapacity() and deallocateCapacity() are meant to throw certain exceptions if the respective operation is unsuccessful.  However, the current code generation in Redhawk 1.9 (and, from the looks of it, in current development) suggests that developers should use the paradigm of calling setAllocator() on the allocation property with an Allocator object.  The Allocator interface is as follows:

```
public interface Allocator<E> {
    public boolean allocate(E capacity);
    public void deallocate(E capacity);
}
```

These methods don't throw the (checked) exception types InvalidCapacity and InvalidState.  I was expecting to be able to throw these during my implementations of allocate() and deallocate for the tuner allocation struct property and let them propagate up to the allocateCapacity() deallocateCapacity() calls, but the lack of @throws statements on the Allocator interface is preventing me from doing so.

My questions are:

1. Am I correct in thinking that developers should be using the setAllocator() approach?
2. If so, is there a way to throw these checked exceptions in the Allocator implementation, or are we discouraged from throwing these in non-generated code?
   2.a.  If throwing these is discouraged, is there any standard way of indicating failure in deallocation?
3. If not, how should we be implementing allocation?  Overriding allocateCapacity() and deallocateCapacity() in the device class directly seems like a poor approach.

I'm developing with Redhawk 1.9.0 on RHEL 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, normally the Allocator interface is the preferred method for implementing allocation. For most cases, the Device base class will handle throwing InvalidState and InvalidCapacity exceptions for you. However, it assumes generic devices, and there are a couple of places in the FRONTEND specification where you are intended to throw an exception that cannot be checked at the base class level, such as whether an allocation ID is valid. Unfortunately, since InvalidState and InvalidCapacity are checked methods, it is not possible to do this directly via the Allocator interface.

There are two ways I can think of around this limitation:

1. Implement your own allocateCapacity() and deallocateCapacity(), which means that you have to reimplement all of the functionality of the base class
2. Throw unchecked exceptions in your allocate() and deallocate()

   - allocate() turns IllegalArgumentException into CF.Device.InvalidCapacity
   - deallocate() turns ArithmeticException and IllegalArgumentException into CF.Device.InvalidCapacity

Prior to 1.9, you would have had to do #1 regardless, so it's not a bad approach. The problem with #2 is that it is a hack, and using IllegalArgumentException will lose the exception's message.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. Do you know if this is the plan for future releases of Redhawk as well?